# How to obtain all possible sub-samples of size n from a dataframe of size N in R?

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, sample

I have a dataframe with 20 classrooms [1 to 20] indexes and 20 different number of students in each class, how to obtain all sub-samples of size n = 8 and store them because i want to use them later for calculations. I used `combn()` but that takes only one vector, can i use it with a dataframe and how? (sorry but i'm new in R), 
dataframe below:

> ```
>    classrooms students
> 1           1       29
> 2           2       30
> 3           3       35
> 4           4       28
> 5           5       32
> 6           6       20
> 7           7       25
> 8           8       22
> 9           9       32
> 10         10       26
> 11         11       27
> 12         12       34
> 13         13       27
> 14         14       28
> 15         15       33
> 16         16       21
> 17         17       36
> 18         18       24
> 19         19       19
> 20         20       32
> ```

Comment: Please add machine-readable code to produce your data frame.  dput() works great for this.

Comment: `read.table('clipboard', header = TRUE)` will work (although `dput` is preferable)

Comment: @mnel, I didn't know you could do that! Very cool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is as simple as passing a function to `combn`. `simplify = FALSE` means that a list will be returned.

Assuming you want all possible combinations of 8 classrooms from the dataset classrooms

```
 combinations <- combn(nrow(classrooms), 8, function(x,data) data[x,], 
                  simplify = FALSE, data =classrooms )

 head(combinations, n = 2)

[[1]]
  classrooms students
1          1       29
2          2       30
3          3       35
4          4       28
5          5       32
6          6       20
7          7       25
8          8       22

[[2]]
  classrooms students
1          1       29
2          2       30
3          3       35
4          4       28
5          5       32
6          6       20
7          7       25
9          9       32
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response, but when i run it an error comes up, > combn(nrow(classrooms),2,function(x,data) data[x,],simplify = FALSE, data=classrooms)
Error in combn(nrow(classrooms), 2, function(x, data) data[x, ], simplify = FALSE,  : 
  n < m

Comment: My solution assumes that your dataset is a data.frame called `classrooms`. If this is the case, my solution should work. (it does for me)

Comment: That's a lot of combinations `ncol(combn(20,8))` = `125970`. Would it be better to just select the combinations when required rather than having a giant list? Something like: `test[combn(nrow(test),8)[,1],]` could be used to generate the data as required.